# How to Secure Firebase in client side Javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, firebase, firebase-security

I am using Firebase with Ruby on Rails (4.0.3). The Client side JS is listening for events on a particular URL. Obviously, the URL is visible to the client, and adding any token based authentication is useless since that'd be visible too. Whats the way around this?

Answer (score 0):

Firebase supports a system of security rules that define who can read or write information in your Firebase. You define them by writing json like this:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "foo": {
      // /foo/ is readable by the world
      ".read": true,

      // /foo/ is writable by the world
      ".write": true,

      // data written to /foo/ must be a string less than 100 characters
      ".validate": "newData.isString() && newData.val().length < 100"
    }
  }
}
```

There's a whole lot more to this topic than is appropriate to put in a Stack Overflow answer, so please check out [Firebase's official documentation on security](https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/guide.html).